# Match values on multiple rows then match differing values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with four columns; firstly I need to match rows across the first three columns. Then, I need to only trigger a match, if the variables are different in column D. Column D inputs are binary C or D. So each matching 'group' must contain at least one C and one D.

Preferably, I would like to add conditional formatting to highlight those rows that trigger a match.

I have been using the formula below to match the first three columns, but I am unable to isolate the results it returns to then perform something along the lines of D1<>D2 (if that is even the most efficient way to go about this).

```
=COUNTIFS($A:A,$A1,$B:B,$B1,$C:C,$C1)>1
```

[Example image - yellow highlight should trigger a match, red should not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Cx9.png)

Comment: how about this : `=COUNTIFS($A:A,$A1,$B:B,$B1,$C:C,$C1,$D:D,IF(D1="D","C","D"))`

Comment: Hi @p._phidot_ thanks for the assist!

This works perfectly. I've added ">0" to the end of the formula to make it a TRUE / FALSE output. 

However, in terms of conditional formatting it appears to be flagging all of the data in the sheet save for column A where it only flags the correct rows. I'm unsure what is triggering the formatting from column B onwards.

I know I'm being a little nit picky here - Any ideas on how to proceed if I want to embed conditional formatting to the spreadsheet rather than adding an addition column with a TRUE / FALSE output as above to highlight the rows?

Comment: Dear Aaron, I'm not really good at setting up formulas for 'conditional formatting', sorry. || But if it was me.. I'll use the true/false column to set up a filter, then highlight/format as I wish, then clear the filter, and do again.

Comment: p/s : I'll put the above answer as the answer post, pls click on the tick. ( :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose :

`=COUNTIFS($A:A,$A1,$B:B,$B1,$C:C,$C1,$D:D,IF(D1="D","C","D"))`

key info :

> Column D inputs are binary C or D

Implementation :

Use an if() in the criteria for count.

Glad it helps. (: